# list iterator problem in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Simple example uses type int

main()
{
   list<string > L;
   L.push_back("test");              // Insert a new element at the end

 L.push_back("testinggggg"); 
 L.push_back("example"); 
   list<string>::iterator i;

   for(i=L.begin(); i != L.end(); ++i) {
       string test = *i;
       cout << test;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am not getting any output if I use the above program and if I change the `string test=*i` to `cout << *i << " ";` it works. What is the problem with this?

Comment: There's no problem with this (besides `int main()`). The code works and outputs everything as expected. You need to finally settle down on some version of the code, since it is impossible to answer when it is changing all the time.

Comment: @AndreyT aye that is one of the annoying things here, you answer the original question, question gets changed then somebody downvotes you for not answering the question. /facepalm.

Comment: raj, I'm inclined to vote for a close. Make up your mind and present an actual problem. The program, as is, seems to be doing what it's supposed to: http://codepad.org/K3qh8oC4

Answer (score 1):

This should not even compile (and it doesn't, on a recent g++).

`i` is an iterator over a `list<int>`, so `*i` is of type `int`. If you assign this to a `string` like this:

```
string test=*i;
```

the compiler will look for a conversion from `int` to `string`. There is no such conversion defined in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Your last for loop you attempt to set the string test to the value of an integer.

You should just try cout << *i << endl;

Comment: sorry that was my mistake and i have changed the programm ..still same error??

Comment: you might try reading i into a temporary int variable with int myInt = *i;  cout << myInt << endl;

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly the error message is?  Is it from the compiler or are you just not getting any output?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me and produces the output:

```
testtestingggggexample
```

You're missing spaces between the words and an `endl` at the end, but the output is there as one would expect.

```
jkugelman$ g++ -Wall -o iterator iterator.cpp 
iterator.cpp:8: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type
jkugelman$ ./iterator 
testtestingggggexamplejkugelman$
```

Answer (score 1):

Working for me. I got this output

testtestingggggexample

I am on Suse g++ 3.4.3 version.